# Agregar atributo "title" en una imagen pasándole el valor contenido en su alt

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Mi problema es el siguiente: tengo un archivo HTML con unas cuantas imágenes (con "id=image") que contienen un atributo "alt". Me piden que agregue un atributo "title" con el valor del "alt" por medio de Jquery

Soy bastante nueva en lo que refiere a Javascript. Investigando un poco por internet llegué a escribir algo de código, pero no me estaría funcionando:

```
// retorna el valor actual del alt del primer elemento #image
var titleElement = $('#image').attr('alt');

document.getElementById('#image').setAttribute('title', titleElement);
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Por lo que dices, creo que el problema no está en el JavaScript que tienes sino en el HTML. Comentas que tienes "varias imágenes" con un id ¿Todas tienen el mismo id?  Si es así, es un error, un id debe ser algo único y el js no funciona porque trata de ponerle el atributo a un elemento único cuando encuentra varios (posiblemente te funcione en la primera imagen con dicho id, pero no en el resto)

Comment: Sí, ese era uno de mis errores... lo que hice para solucionarlo fue ponerle a todas las imágenes un atributo "name" en vez de un "id", y llamé desde el script a ese atributo name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#image').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("title",$(this).attr('alt'));
});
```